# How to access optional shape field in hack?

Tags: hacklang

To give an example, let's assume I have a type `foo` of the following shape,

```
type foo = shape(
  ?'bar' => float,
  ...
);
```

Now if I try to access value of field `bar` in the following way,

```
do_something_with($rcvd['bar']);
```

where `$rcvd` is of `foo` type, it doesn't work as `bar` is an optional member and might not exist for the instance `$rcvd`.
So for this given example, the question would be - how to access the member `bar` of `$rcvd`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found it: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/HH.Shapes/idx/

So the correct way is,

```
Shapes::idx($rcvd, 'bar');
```

Comment: At some point (this may have already happened?) the notion of "nullable fields" and "optional fields" will get separated. What you have there is IIRC an optional but non-nullable field; you may want to try `'bar' => ?float` for a required but optional field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Shapes::idx` method as you mentioned in your answer.

but you can also use null coalesce operator, which you might be more familiar with from other programming languages such as [PHP](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) and [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

see : https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/expressions-and-operators/coalesce

example :

```php
type Foo = shape(
  'bar' => ?int,
  ?'baz' => int,
);

function qux(Foo $foo): int {
  $default = 1;
  // foo[bar] is null ? set default.
  $bar = $foo['bar'] ?? $default;
  // foo[baz] doesn't exist ? set default.
  $baz = $foo['baz'] ?? $default;
  return $baz + $bar;
}

<<__EntryPoint>>
async function main(): Awaitable<noreturn> {
  echo qux(shape(
    'bar' => null,
  )); // 2
  echo qux(shape(
    'bar' => 0,
  )); // 1
  echo qux(shape(
    'bar' => 1,
  )); // 2
  echo qux(shape(
    'bar' => 4,
    'baz' => 2,
  )); // 6
  echo qux(shape(
    'bar' => null,
    'baz' => 0
  )); // 1
}
```

Hack also support null coalesce equal operator.

example :

```php
// foo[bar] is null ? set foo[bar] to default
$foo['bar'] ??= $default;

// foo[baz] is missing ? set foo[baz] to default
$foo['baz'] ??= $default;
```